# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextCleanupListener

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, deployment

I have a webapp built using spring framework. I'm trying to deploy this to Tomcat6 using Eclipse. Everytime i make a change to jsp file, I had to clean the build, publish it & then start the server. I believe, we don't have to do all these steps for JSP changes. If i just publish the files, when the server is running, i get the below exceptions

> SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextCleanupListener
>
> SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer

And the war file is not getting deployed in server.

If I make a change to JSP file & then click restart in eclipse, it sometimes publish the files & then start the server. But in some cases, it restarts the server & then publishes the files (in which case i got the above mentioned exceptions & the war file was not getting deployed).

Ideal way that it works is, Stop the server, publish the contents & then start the server. I hate to do this every time i make a simple jsp change. Is there any alternate one click process to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with the way you setup your project or server in Eclipse. I'd recommend following the instructions [here](http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/08/10/configuring-eclipse-tomcat-spring). Also, you may want to download [STS](http://www.springsource.com/downloads/sts) (Eclipse already bundled with Spring support) and use that instead of the vanilla eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that spring is deployed together with your application. Either set the correct export options in eclipse or copy the spring libraries to /WEB-INF/lib.

[MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com) works fine here. You could also check [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) as well. They advertise no redeployments. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use exploded war and incremental hot-deploy.

this should work http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMtcjgTyP-g

folow at 2:30