# Redeploying webapp on tomcat causes java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

My tomcat logs get flooded with this whenever I redeploy an app.

```
2015-11-25 08:09:16 SEVERE org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextCleanupListener
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1028)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy(HostConfig.java:1478)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1406)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1626)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:328)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        ... 16 more
```

What causes it?

Comment: The spring-web.jar is missing?

Comment: nope. All apps have it

Comment: try to kill all java processes. On linux by sudo killall java . Then, can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a duplication of some of:
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextCleanupListener issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323701/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-web-context-contextcleanupli)

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextCleanupListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170801/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-web-context-contextcleanupli)

[Tomcat & Spring Web - Class Not Found Exception org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322711/tomcat-spring-web-class-not-found-exception-org-springframework-web-context)

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/52595-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-con-text-contextloaderlistener